# Dynamic bindings with let in Hy?

Tags: hy

Comming from Common Lisp, I'm trying to use let to shadow the value of a global variable dynamically.

```
(setv glob 18)

(defn callee []
  (print glob))

(defn nonl [x]
  (callee)
  (let [glob x]
    (callee))
  (callee))

(nonl 39)

=>
18
18
18
```

Is there a way to make this work so that the second call to callee gives 39?

[EDIT]

Based on gilch's response i wrote the following draft using contextvars:

```
(import contextvars :as cv)

(defmacro defparam [symbol value]
  (let [command (. f"{symbol} = cv.ContextVar('{symbol}')")]
    `(do (exec ~command)
         (.set ~symbol ~value))))

(defmacro parameterize [symbol value #* body]
  `(. (cv.copy-context)
      (run (fn [] (do (.set ~symbol ~value)
                      ~@body)))))

(defn callee []
  (glob.get))

;;;;;;;;;

(defparam glob 18)

(callee)                  => 18
(parameterize glob 39
  (callee))               => 39
(callee)                  => 18
```

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to give a global variable a dynamically scoped temporary value in Python (and Hy doesn't add a macro for it or anything), so you have to do it yourself:

```
(setv glob 18)

(defn callee []
  (print glob))

(defn nonl [x]
  (callee)
  (global glob)
  (setv old-glob glob)
  (try
    (setv glob x)
    (callee)
    (finally
      (setv glob old-glob)))
  (callee))

(nonl 39)
```

A macro for this might look like:

```
(defmacro dyn-rebind-global [symbol new-value #* body]
  (setv temp (hy.gensym))
  `(do
    (global ~symbol)
    (setv ~temp ~symbol)
    (try
      (setv ~symbol ~new-value)
      ~@body
      (finally
        (setv ~symbol ~temp)))))
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
(setv glob 18)

(defn callee []
  (print glob))

(defn nonl [x]
  (callee)
  (dyn-rebind-global glob x
    (callee))
  (callee))

(nonl 39)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that.

Comment: This would be a fun addition to Hyrule!

Answer (score 2):

The nearest Python equivalents of dynamic bindings are [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#module-contextvars) and [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch).

`patch` is mainly intended for unit testing and works on pretty much anything, but is not thread safe. If you need to dynamically rebind something in library code, `patch` can do it. Use as a context manager or decorator.

```py
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> name = 'Alice'
>>> def greet(): print("Hi", name)
...
>>> greet()
Hi Alice
>>> with patch('__main__.name', 'Bob'):
...     greet()
...
Hi Bob
>>> greet()
Hi Alice
```

With `contextvars` it has to be set up as a `ContextVar` in the first place at the module top level, and has to be explicitly dereferenced with `.get()` calls, but it works properly in threaded and async code.

If you want to declare your own dynamic variables in Python, it's best to make it a context var when async or threading is a possibility. An asyncio task manager will automatically swap in a new context for each task. You can also do this manually with `copy_context`. The `run()` method takes a callable, so it can work as a decorator:

```py
>>> import contextvars as cv
>>> name = cv.ContextVar('name', default='Alice')
>>> def greet(): print('Hi', name.get())
...
>>> greet()
Hi Alice
>>> @cv.copy_context().run
... def _():
...   name.set('Bob')
...   greet()
...
Hi Bob
>>> greet()
Hi Alice
```

This can all work exactly the same way in Hy, but a macro could make it nicer.

Comment: These are some interesting ideas, but writing the example code in Hy would be more helpful to readers than writing it in Python.

Comment: Contextvar is the safest solution in this case, even though it's fun to reimplement dynamic bindings with a macro. This is because Contextvars are already designed to work properly in the context of threads or async concurrency. See [PEP 555](https://peps.python.org/pep-0555/) for more on this subject. Maybe it's possible to come up with a clever macro interface that hides the `ContextVar` boilerplate behind something more akin to Lisp special variables.